# Vue - Where to put v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Where can I put this `v-for` line so that it does not impact the styling of my component?

This is my `v-for` statement"

```
<v-flex xs12 v-for="(rates, index) in weight_based_rates" :key="rates.id">
```

I've tried it on `template` `v-layout` and like above in a `v-flex` (I'm using vuetify)

It either destroys my layout or in the case of putting it on `v-layout` I get an error saying I can't put it on those types of elements.

I need to access the data in those text and number fields.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs1 fill-height>
      <v-icon 
        medium 
        color="green darken-3"
        @click="addWeightComponent()"
      >add_circle_outline</v-icon>

      <v-icon
        medium
        color="red darken-4"
        @click=""
      >remove_circle_outline</v-icon>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs4 pl-3 >
      <v-text-field
        :key="rates.id"
        color="purple darken-3"
        v-model="rates.rate_name"
        label="Shipping Rate Name"
        class="move-up"
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs1 pl-3>            
      <v-text-field
        type="number"
        color="purple darken-3"
        label="Min"

      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs1 pl-3>            
      <v-text-field
        type="number"
        color="purple darken-3"
        label="Max"

      ></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs3 offset-xs1>
      <v-text-field
        type="number"
        color="purple darken-3"
        label="Weight Based Rate Amount"

        :prefix="standard_currency_symbol"
        class="move-up"
      ></v-text-field>
     </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

Comment: Where do you want to put it?

Comment: @Phiter as "high" up on the page as possible. So I can access the data in those v-text fields

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can only put it on content elements so not on (v-layout or template tags)

```
<template>
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex v-for="(item, index) in object">
     {{item}}
     <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

wrap your content accordingly to what is valid in the loop. ;). Hope that makes sense.